# Default Words For Php

Tags: php, if-statement

Is there any way to like do a default code, i don't know how to explain this but i will try my best to.

```
<?php
if ($test == "CODE-*AnyWordHere*"){
    echo "Yes";
}
?>
```

Another Example:

```
<?php
if ($url == "http://stackoverflow.com/secretplace/index.html/?*AnyWordHere*"){
    echo "Yes";
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't know about the others but I didn't understand what you want ...

Comment: Really? You selected and code marked-up *every line*? You could have just selected the whole code block and clicked `{}`.

Comment: You can use regular expressions to do this and much more. http://webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for, but here are a few guesses.

If you want to check for a variable string in an if statement you can use either strstr or strpos to see if a string exists in another one. To use the example you provided, try the following:

```
<?php
if (strstr($test, "CODE-")) {
    echo "Yes";
}
?>
```

If you want to retrieve that variable part of the string you're checking, try this:

```
<?php
$str_to_check = "CODE-*AnyWordHere*"

if ($pos = strpos($test, $str_to_check) !== false)) {
    $code = substr($str_to_check, $pos, len($str_to_check));
    echo $code;
}
?>
```

If you simply want to using a variable string in a control statement, try this:

```
<?php
if ($test == "CODE-" . $any_word_here){
    echo "Yes";
}
?>
```

The period joins (concatenate) two strings together.

If none of these suffice, then I'm not sure what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for [strstr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) which will match to see if a string contains another string like this:

```
<?php
    $email  = 'http://stackoverflow.com/secretplace/index.html/?someTerm';
    $domain = strstr($email, 'someTerm');
    if ($domain)
    {
        // Your 'someTerm' was found in the string.
    }
?>
```

Comment: @MatthewJones Sorry, I just don't understand what it is you are asking then :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `strpos()` or:

```
function strending($string, $keyword){
    return substr($string, strlen($string)-strlen($keyword), strlen($string)) == $keyword;
}

strending("hello world", "world"); //true
strending("hello world!", "world"); //false
```

Not sure if this is what you mean. You can also try to use `regexp`.